# Interceptor is called 2 times more

Tags: java, spring, internationalization, interceptor

I use Spring i18n library. 
- ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource 
- SessionLocaleResolver 
- LocaleChangeInterceptor

There are no errors.
If I use a strong refresh function in chrome, all interceptor methods are executed twice more. 
And The Issue only occurs when the pages is used messages.properties.

preHandle ==> Controller ==> postHandle ==> AfterCompletion is executed, and all methods are executed twice more.

I've looked at the lifecycle of the interceptor, but I don't understand why the interceptor runs twice more without reason.

1. servlet-context.xml

```
<beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basenames" value="/WEB-INF/messages/messages, /WEB-INF/messages/messages_ko_KR" />
</beans:bean>    
<beans:bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <beans:property name="defaultLocale" value="ko_KR" />
</beans:bean>
<interceptors>
    <beans:bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="com.test.util.locale.LocaleChangeInterceptor" />
</interceptors>
```

2. LocaleChangeInterceptor is implemented by me and is implemented as simple as the code below.

```
public class LocaleChangeInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {

        String language = request.getParameter("language");

        System.out.println("1. preHandle(): " + language);

        if(language != null) {
            LocaleResolver localeResolver = RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request);
            localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, StringUtils.parseLocaleString(language));
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("2. postHandle()");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("3. afterCompletion()");
    }
}
```

Console

```
1. preHandle(): null
main.jsp
2. postHandle()
3. afterCompletion()
1. preHandle(): null
2. postHandle()
3. afterCompletion()
1. preHandle(): null
2. postHandle()
3. afterCompletion()
```

I don't know whether it is a problem or a natural result of Interceptor's lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. 
It was resolved by first creating an Interceptor bean, 
then by calling the registered bean by reference from the .

It seems to be an issue because I didn't know well about Spring interceptor registration. I need to find out more.

```
<beans:bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="com.test.util.locale.LocaleChangeInterceptor" />

<interceptors>
    <interceptor>
        <mapping path="/**" />
        <exclude-mapping path="/resources/**" />
        <beans:ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    </interceptor>
</interceptors>
```